# Duplicate class in an android studio project using java

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, mobile-development

[image]

**This is the github rep link**
[Github rep](https://github.com/Oussemasahbeni/My_First_APP) 
i kept getting this error everytime i rebuild the app

`Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable`

im working on the latest version of android studio

> Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

the project is Build Your First Android App in Java
this is the link :https://developer.android.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app#0
i noticed that some code snippets are outdated so its 100% identical

## ****this is the build.gradle.kts(Porject: My_First_App)**

```
plugins{     id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false     id("androidx.navigation.safeargs") version "2.5.3" apply false }
```

**this is the build.gradle.kts(Module:app)

```
   plugins {
        id("com.android.application")
        id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
    }


    android {
        namespace = "com.example.myfirstapp"
        compileSdk = 33

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "com.example.myfirstapp"
            minSdk = 24
            targetSdk = 33
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                isMinifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
        }
    }
    val nav_version = "2.5.3"
    dependencies {

        implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
        implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version")
        implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version")
        implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
        implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3")
        implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
        implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    }
```

Comment: I updated it to id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false and seems to be working fine, built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

in dependencies

ie:

```
dependencies {

       constraints {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
        }
        implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
        implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version")
        implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version")
        implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
        implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3")
        implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
        implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
        androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    }
```

[source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_pp4SIYMcw][1]